# VDATE format ISOFORMATED date

Tags: oracle

i have some question with oracle query, Sorry for my english, i want try to select data with new latest around date vdate='2022-11-10' with PS='S' and with TRAD='ASRI', and order by VDate DESC i can manage query from like picture i make in bottom.

[image: 1]

and my problem is i want to filter data with VDATE. i try query VDATE like format i ask up. but it doesnt work. please help me with my case. thanks

Comment: Do not post images. Instead, post code as formatted text. Most people will pass over your question if there is a link to an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
select t.* from fxdh t where t.vdate between to_date(‘2022-11-10’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD’) /* your reference date */ - 7 /* days */ and to_date(‘2022-11-10’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD) /* your reference date */ + 7 /* days */ and t.trad = ‘ASRI’ and t.ps = ‘S’ order by t.vdate asc
```

This would match the records (if any) within the window of plus or minus 7 days from the reference date (for ghe given trader).

…although from the screenshot looks like more SQL Server than Oracle rdbms to me.